# TypeORM default/force values on table

Tags: typescript, express, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working in a project with **TypeORM** (MariaDB) in **NestJS**, I have a *"groups"* tables, it has a *'name'* and *'permissions'* columns, I want to set values for this table with ADMIN and DEFAULT roles. These roles shouldn't be able to be removed (They also have a column *'deleteable'* as boolean).

I'm new using TypeORM and SQL databases and I don't know what I have to do to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, "**[onModuleInit](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/lifecycle-events#lifecycle-events-1)**" (from Lifecycle events) method inside a module, this method will be called every time module is loaded (also after database connection):

```
@Module({...})
export class RolesModule {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(RoleEntity)
    private readonly repository: Repository<RoleEntity>,
  ) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    // Use "repository" to interact with table and create default values in case roles not exists.
  }
}
```